# Why is my device listed multiple times in ADB?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb

Why is this happening?

```
PS C:\> adb devices
List of devices attached
10004dd7bcde    offline
10004dd7bcde    offline
10004dd7bcde    offline
10004dd7bcde    offline
10004dd7bcde    offline
10004dd7bcde    offline
10004dd7bcde    offline
```

If I wait 30 seconds more, X new "devices" are listed. I can fix the problem by running `adb kill-server` and disconnect and reconnect the device, but this is not a satisfactory solution. The problem reoccurs several times per hour and slows down my work significantly

adb is version 1.0.31. I usually run IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3 in parallell when this happens, but I don't know if it is related.

Comment: That's wild. What device is this?

Comment: Has happeneed both with Samsung Galaxy 1 and HTC One

Comment: I'd start with replacing your USB cable. This usually happens when the device gets disconnected in the middle of adb transaction.